# Помогите разобраться в сигнатуре метода c#

Tags: c#

Поясните пожалуйста сигнатуру метода: понятно что это метод расширения и понятно что в круглых скобках два параметра. Непонятно что написано в угловых скобках - таких мест тут три и все они одинаковые и содержат по три параметра, разделенных запятыми:

```
 public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>
     WithParameter<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(
         this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> registration,
         Parameter parameter)
```

Comment: [Универсальные классы и методы (Generics)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)

Comment: В `IRegistrationBuilder<...>` эти параметры типа просто дублируются. Вызываешь `WithParameter<A, B, C>()`, он возвращает интерфейс именно с такими параметрами типа `IRegistrationBuilder<A, B, C>`

Comment: Спасибо большое . .. где я могу поставить вам плюсик за ответ ?